# Predefined Libraries in Progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Is there any "pre defined libraries" present in progress4GL?Like Math.h in C.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of useful libraries at oehive.org.

There are also some interesting things in $DLC/src.  ".pl" files are "Progress Libraries", they contain collections of files that you can run so long as the .pl is in the PROPATH.

Comprehensive documentation of what can be found where is "weak".

Comment: Especially like the last line... so true.

Answer (score 0):

You can link in an outside library, but outside of that - no. Support for all the language elements are already built-into the virtual machine that runs the ABL code.